# What does 'lambda do?

Tags: emacs, lambda

This is the source code from emacs. What does the `'lambda` do in `(eq transient-mark-mode 'lambda)`?

```
(defun handle-shift-selection ()
  (cond ((and shift-select-mode this-command-keys-shift-translated)
     (unless (and mark-active
          (eq (car-safe transient-mark-mode) 'only))
   (setq-local transient-mark-mode
                   (cons 'only
                         (unless (eq transient-mark-mode 'lambda)
                           transient-mark-mode)))
       (push-mark nil nil t)))
    ((eq (car-safe transient-mark-mode) 'only)
     (setq transient-mark-mode (cdr transient-mark-mode))
     (if (eq transient-mark-mode (default-value 'transient-mark-mode))
         (kill-local-variable 'transient-mark-mode))
     (deactivate-mark))))
```

Comment: It's standard lisp evaluation. `'lambda` gets evaluated to `lambda` (a symbol) and `transient-mark-mode` gets evaluated to whatever it is bound to and then `eq` is applied with those as arguments. If they are the very same symbol the result will be `t`

Comment: Thanks. I did not alert that `transient-mark-mode` can be of value `'lambda`. Using `'lambda` as symbol is so confusing.

Comment: `C-h v transient-mark-mode`